# Somar e Multiplicar valores sem refresh à partir de button e input

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde.

Preciso fazer um cálculo sem refresh, porém estou encontrando dificuldades. Vou tentar explicar isso na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var xazul = 0;
  function buttonazul1() {
    document.getElementById('output-azul').innerHTML = ++xazul;
  }

  function buttonazul2() {
    document.getElementById('output-azul').innerHTML = --xazul;
  }
</script>

<table style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="buttonazul2()">
        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i>
      </button>
    </td>                        
    <td>
      <span id="output-azul">0</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="buttonazul1()">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Programei o botão para acrescentar +1 ao SPAN, para que o cliente escolha a quantidade de cada produto. Preciso pegar esse valor, multiplicar com o valor unitário do produto, que vou deixar num campo `hidden`, mostrar o subtotal e depois somar toda a coluna do subtotal para dar o total final da compra.

Enfim, esse é o melhor método? Existe um método melhor? Como poderia realizar esses cálculos, apenas ao clicar no botão de 'mais' e 'menos'?

Comment: Repliquei o seu código e ele não reproduziu erros...

Comment: Opa! A parte do '+' e '-' funciona normal. Só queria entender a lógica pra fazer essa conta.

Comment: Eu estou tentando fazer a operação que descrevi na imagem, só que não consegui criar a lógica para realizar todos estes cálculos sem refresh.

Comment: @CyberPlague, Minha instrução não foi para reaproveitar a pergunta. É criar uma nova pergunta, ficou boa desse jeito, o código, de preferencia, deve ser colocado direto na pergunta os usuários preferem assim. E na nova pergunta retire a parte do refresh que já foi solucionada.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/413058/somar-subtrair-extrair-subtotal-e-total-final-com-javascript-jquery

Comment: @CyberPlague, a pergunta ficou muito boa.  Deixei o +1. Vi que já teve uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema considere aceitá-la. Caso tenha dúvidas sobre como aceitar uma resposta leia [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Answer (score 2):

Primeira coisa que eu fiz foi replicar seu exemplo:

```js
var xazul = 0;

function buttonazul1() {
  document.getElementById('output-azul').innerHTML = ++xazul;
}

function buttonazul2() {
  document.getElementById('output-azul').innerHTML = --xazul;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="buttonazul2()">
        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i>
      </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="output-azul">0</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="buttonazul1()">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i>
      </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Ao executar pude constatar o que já foi levantado nos comentário, que o comportamento descrito não acontece. Então voltei meu foco para imagem na questão e me ocorreu que esse código poderia estar inserido dentro de um `<form>`. Então fiz o teste:

```js
var xazul = 0;

function buttonazul1() {
  document.getElementById('output-azul').innerHTML = ++xazul;
}

function buttonazul2() {
  document.getElementById('output-azul').innerHTML = --xazul;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="buttonazul2()">
        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i>
      </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="output-azul">0</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="buttonazul1()">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i>
      </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

E realmente ocorreu o problema descrito, logo após clicar um botão o formulário é enviado e é preciso dar um refresh para visualizar a página.

Isso ocorre porque declarou o elemento `<button>` com o atributo `type="submit"` que significa que seu comportamento é enviar os dados do formulário para o servidor.

Para mudar esse comportamento deve declarar o elemento  `<button>` com o atributo `type="button"` que permite ao botão ter scripts do lado do cliente associado com seus eventos.

[Documentação do elemento `<button>`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

```js
var xazul = 0;

function buttonazul1() {
  document.getElementById('output-azul').innerHTML = ++xazul;
}

function buttonazul2() {
  document.getElementById('output-azul').innerHTML = --xazul;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="buttonazul2()">
        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i>
      </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="output-azul">0</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="buttonazul1()">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i>
      </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por seu tempo! Agora, como informei antes, preciso pegar o valor de cada produto, que posso deixar numa variável, sem problemas. Quando a pessoa clicar no mais ou no menos, preciso fazer o cálculo do valor fixo * quantidade, para ter o subtotal que está ao lado. Estou tentando aqui, mas confesso que não tenho habilidade ainda com jQuery ou Javascript.

Comment: @CyberPlague eu estou lendo as atualizações que fez na pergunta.

Comment: Agradeço! Eu gostaria de jogar esses valores em variáveis, para o código ficar mais limpo. Agora, estou tentando somar todos os "subtotais" para gerar o total.

Comment: A pergunta está fora do formato da página, aumentou o seu escopo. Eu recomendo que retire as atualizações dessa pergunta, porque da maneira que está vão fechar por estar ampla demais. Sugiro que abra uma nova pergunta específica para questão da soma e subtotais só seria interessante colocar o código em que você realmente está trabalhando pois esse exemplo não se encaixa mais com o que está perguntando pois quando você explica seu problema você explica da ótica do código que gerou aquela imagem mas nos que lemos só temos o código do exemplo para trabalhar gerando um vazio cognitivo.

Comment: Augusto, obrigado mais uma vez. Na verdade, tudo está dentro do que pedi no início, mas realmente coloquei texto demais. Vou editar a pergunta, pra ficar mais fácil.

Comment: O ideal seria o código da página da imagem. Poxa o exemplo só tem uma linha como vou fazer um somatório de uma só linha. A pagina da imagem tem seis linhas. Tudo bem que fazer um somatório de inputs com jquery é basicamente `var soma = 0;
$('.subtotais').each(function(){
    sum += this.value;
});` mas eu não posso inserir isso no seu código as cegas. Seria irresponsabilidade minha.

Comment: Devo postar o código completo? Poxa, me perdoe, faço isso sem problemas!

Comment: Isso... faça uma nova pergunta, baseada no código completo ou se for muito grande publique apenas o <form> que contenha os elementos contendo os valores a serem somados e multiplicados, assim como elemento que receberá o total.

Comment: Tô jogando no Pastebin, pra ficar mais limpo.

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo de uma função, não entendi muito bem o que você quer, ela faz a conta:

```
function upPreco() {
var Valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
var Pagamento = document.getElementById("total").value;
var Desconto = document.getElementById("desconto").value;
var Mora = document.getElementById("mora").value;
var Multa = document.getElementById("multa").value;
var Outros = document.getElementById("outros").value;
var Total = 0;
var TotalSoma = 0;
var Saldo = 0;
TotalSoma = Number(Mora.replace(/[R\$ \.]/g, '').replace(',', '.')) + Number(Multa.replace(/[R\$ \.]/g, '').replace(',', '.')) + Number(Outros.replace(/[R\$ \.]/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
Total = Number(Valor.replace(/[R\$ \.]/g, '').replace(',', '.')) - Number(Desconto.replace(/[R\$ \.]/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
Total = Total + TotalSoma;
Saldo = Total - Number(Pagamento.replace(/[R\$ \.]/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
$("#saldo").val(Saldo.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
 }
```

e você chama ela no evento `onclick`, do + ou -, que não irá realizar o `refresh`.

Comment: `var xAzul = 0;
            var Valor = 150;

            function buttonazul1() {
            
              document.getElementById('quantidadeAzul').innerHTML = ++xAzul;

              var SubTotalAzul = 0;

              SubTotalAzul = xAzul * Valor;

              $("SubTotal").val(SubTotalAzul.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));

            }`

Comment: Não consigo implantar, tem algo errado.